# Where are the mods?

Tags: discussion

Only one day left for nomination and I don't see any of our present moderators participating. Any reason why they refrain from this or it's a coincidence?

Comment: Ironically, even though our mod status is not at stake in the current elections, the current mods [are technically allowed to nominate themselves](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234445/145951). What would happen if re-elected is unclear.

Answer (score 8):

This election is to *add* one more moderator to the team. The four current moderators will continue to serve along with whoever wins this election.